# SELECT with CASE fail when aggregate function is used

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following t-sql query.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE(
    Points INT
    ,PointsOf INT
)
INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES (3,12),(2,12),(3,12),(11,12),(12,12),(5,12),(0,12)

DECLARE @Decimal TINYINT = 2


SELECT  
    CASE @Decimal
        WHEN 0 THEN CAST(CAST(SUM(Points) AS DECIMAL(18,0)) / NULLIF(SUM(PointsOf), 0) * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,0))
        WHEN 1 THEN CAST(CAST(SUM(Points) AS DECIMAL(18,1)) / NULLIF(SUM(PointsOf), 0) * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,1))
        WHEN 2 THEN CAST(CAST(SUM(Points) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) / NULLIF(SUM(PointsOf), 0) * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
    END  AS Score
FROM @Test
```

I have an variable `@Decimals`. When the variable is 0 I need my query to return score in XX format, when its 1 in XX.X format and when its 2 in the XX.XX format.
What happen here is that the CASE enter multiple THEN clauses. When the query above is executed i get 44.86 as result which is correct, but when i change the `@Decimals` valiable to 0 i get a result 44.00 which is incorect. Its suppose to return just 44 without decimals. The same thing happen when i have `@Decimals` at 1, it returns 44.90 when it has to be 44.9.

Does any one know why this happen?

Comment: @HughJones, there is a `NULIIF` check, to in a case of zero, a `NULL` is returned. So, divided by zero is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24887045/300863) quite rightly points out the case statement is converting this to the smallest possible data type to hold all the result types. (See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx), specifically the **Return Types** section)

From my point of view, this is merely a display issue. You want to display `44.9` and not `44.90` (note the trailing zero) when the `@decimal` variable is set to one.

One way to do this is to add an additional cast to varchar. It's not pretty and not something I would recommend doing but if you insist on doing formatting and UI type things in SQL Server then what can you do?

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE(
    Points INT
    ,PointsOf INT
)
INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES (3,12),(2,12),(3,12),(11,12),(12,12),(5,12),(0,12)

DECLARE @Decimal TINYINT = 1


SELECT  
    CASE @Decimal
        WHEN 0 THEN cast(Cast(CAST(SUM(Points) AS DECIMAL(18,0)) / NULLIF(SUM(PointsOf), 0) * 100 as decimal(18,0)) as varchar(10))
        WHEN 1 THEN cast(Cast(CAST(SUM(Points) AS DECIMAL(18,1)) / NULLIF(SUM(PointsOf), 0) * 100 as decimal(18,1))as varchar(10))
        WHEN 2 THEN cast(Cast(CAST(SUM(Points) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) / NULLIF(SUM(PointsOf), 0) * 100 as decimal(18,2))as varchar(10))
    END  AS Score
FROM @Test
```

Comment: When I try to cast the value mentioned in my answer as decimal(18,x) with 0, 1 and 2, I get results formatted as shown in my answer. What would cause that? I'm also using SQL Server 2012. http://rextester.com/HJJKF88090

Comment: @shree.pat18 Because these statements are executed separately. If you combined them in a `CASE` statement, it seems that the returned value for each `THEN` statement should be the same type. And in this case the results are cast automatically to `DECIMAL(18,2)`

Comment: @shree.pat18 Exactly what @ gotqn has said!

Comment: Thanks @gotqn! I didn't know `CASE` would does this. Is this documented, or a gotcha?

Comment: No, [this is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx) `Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.`

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how MS Server works, but according to the ANSI SQL spec, a column always has one specific data type, which in this case is decimal(20,2), i.e. the smallest data type that can store all of the case's different result types.